# set events to DOM objects using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some DOM inputs and I added some events to them, the inputs are like:

```
$("#hotel2city").keyup(function(){
    getDestinations($("#hotel2city"));
});

$("#hotel2name").keyup(function(){
    getHotels($("#hotel2city").val(),$("#hotel2name"));
});
```

which works, what I want to do is to not repeat every time the above code but to have a for loop that attach the events. So I wrote an IIFE:

```
var setControlls = function(){
    for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
        $("#hotel" + i +"city").keyup(function(){
                getDestinations($("#hotel"+i+"city"));
        });

        $("#hotel"+i+"name").keyup(function(){
            getHotels($("#hotel"+i+"city").val(),$("#hotel"+i+"name"));
        });
    }
}();
```

but this does not work, any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class to add the event once to all the elements, then use the ID of the element to perform the specific functionality you want inside the listener:

```
<input type='text' class='keyup-hotel-input' id="hotel2name">
<input type='text' class='keyup-hotel-input' id="hotel2city">
...
<input type='text' class='keyup-hotel-input' id="hotel5name">
<input type='text' class='keyup-hotel-input' id="hotel5city">

$('.keyup-hotel-input').on('keyup',function(e) {
   if(this.id.match('city')) {
       getDestinations($(this).val());
   } else {
       getHotels($(this).val());
   }
});
```

Comment: I like that solution, I should though this earlier. Thank you Adam.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to give it a class and then a `data-id` or something, so its scalable.:

HTML:

```
<div class="hotelCity" data-id="10"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(".hotelCity").on("keyup", function(){
    getDestinations($(this).data("id"));
});
```

And so on.

The issue you have is the scope, the `i` will always be the highest number. If you want to solve your issue, use this:

```
var setControlls = function(){
    for(var i=1; i<=5; i++){
        (function(j){ // Create scope
            $("#hotel" + j +"city").keyup(function(){
              getDestinations($("#hotel"+j+"city"));
            });

            $("#hotel"+i+"name").keyup(function(){
                getHotels($("#hotel"+j+"city").val(),$("#hotel"+j+"name"));
            });
        })(i); // Call scope j=i;
    }
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a class to them and pass the id of the element to the function instead of writing multiple events on id basis:

```
<input id="hotel2city" class="hotelcity"/>

<input id="hotel2name" class="hotelname"/>
```

and write event on class selector:

```
$(".hotelcity").keyup(function(){
    getDestinations(this.id);
});

$(".hotelname").keyup(function(){
    getHotels($(this).val(),this);
});
```